# HTML5 input type Color read single RGB values

Tags: javascript, html

With this code on browser many field are available by the user, it can change R,G,B, HEX VALUE, HUE ecc.
I need to read only the Red value.

```
  <input id="color_pick"type="color" value="#ff0000">

var toread = document.getElementById('color_pick');
toread.value # get the hex 
toread.value.red() # would it be possible to get r?
```

I've read this document but cannot figure how to get the single R value from the input.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/color

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Furthermore, the code you posted won't run, as the browser can execute either HTML code or javascript, and your code has both.

Comment: The document you link to says that the `value` is a string, not a special color type. Also, what do you expect the red value to be? "ff"? 255?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have hexadecimal from `node.value` property, you just have to convert it to integer.

```js
function pickRedInt(){
  var toread = document.getElementById('color_pick');
  console.log("Red Value - "+parseInt("0x"+toread.value.slice(1,3)));
}

pickRedInt();
```

```html
Try changing this:
<hr>
<input id="color_pick"type="color" value="#ff0000" onchange="pickRedInt()">
```

Comment: Or just use the radix argument to `parseInt`, `parseInt(value, 16)` and forgo the "0x" concatenation. Either way. But this has been asked and answered many times over.

Comment: Noticed that in @Wendelin's answer. It's neat, but I wouldn't prefer to edit and steal something that he added here.

Answer (score 9):

There is no direct way to get the individual color values but it can be easily done manually.

```js
function printColor(ev) {
  const color = ev.target.value
  const r = parseInt(color.substr(1,2), 16)
  const g = parseInt(color.substr(3,2), 16)
  const b = parseInt(color.substr(5,2), 16)
  console.log(`red: ${r}, green: ${g}, blue: ${b}`)
}
```

```html
<input type="color" onchange="printColor(event)" value="#ff0000">
```

The value of a color input is always a seven character long hex color string, so there are no difficult edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

This method work perfect already have in the top of this questions

```html
<input type="color" onchange="printColor(event)">
  <script>
      function printColor(ev) {
          const color = ev.target.value
          const r = parseInt(color.substr(1, 2), 16)
          const g = parseInt(color.substr(3, 2), 16)
          const b = parseInt(color.substr(5, 2), 16)
          console.log(`red: ${r}, green: ${g}, blue: ${b}`)
          console.log([r, g, b])
          alert(`R: ${r}, G: ${g}, B: ${b}`)
      }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get RGB color Code From Hex Code</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="color" id="choose-color" />

<script>
    var choose_color = document.getElementById("choose-color");
    choose_color.onchange = function(){
        var hex_code = this.value.split("");
        var red = parseInt(hex_code[1]+hex_code[2],16);
        var green = parseInt(hex_code[3]+hex_code[4],16);
        var blue = parseInt(hex_code[5]+hex_code[6],16);
        var rgb = red+","+green+","+blue;
        alert(rgb);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check it here - https://jaischool.com/javascript-lang/convert-hex-code-in-rgb-color-format.html